# Post YouTube comment with Internet Explorer

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I am trying to comment on YouTube videos with IE video links are opening fine but comment box input value and comment button code giving error (Object variable not set (Error 91)

```
Sub test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ie As Object: Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
Dim i, lastRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

ie.Visible = True


lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


' On Error Resume Next

For i = 1 To lastRow
    ie.navigate ws.Cells(i, 1)

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    Loop
```

comment box input value (Object variable not set (Error 91)

```
        Dim iDOC As MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set iDOC = ie.document
        iDOC.getElementsByTagName("div").Item("comment-simplebox-text").Value = "nice video"
```

comment box click (Object variable not set (Error 91)

```
     Dim doc_ele As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
      Dim doc_eles As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection: Set doc_eles = 
    iDOC.getElementsByTagName("button")


For Each doc_ele In doc_eles
If doc_ele.className = "style-scope ytd-commentbox style-primary size-default" Then
doc_ele.Click
Else
End If
Next
Next
MsgBox "done"
 ' ie.Quit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: "can't give value in comment input box" - why not? What code are you using to do that? What happens when you try?

Comment: In order to be able to post any comment programmatically on any youtube videos, your script has to log you in first.

Comment: @halfer I provided the code which I am using

Comment: @sim I am already logged in, in youtube with my account before running the code

Comment: @LifeStyle: when you say you are logged in, where are you logged in? The internet browser you are using may be a separate instance of IE, and is probably not the same one you can see on your desktop.

Comment: @halfer when I am running macro I can see my account logged in on YouTube pages its also showing my account logo on sign in place